# add objects to JSON array

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I've been looking into/using web service and I managed to extract and use JSON text from a server. At the moment, Im looking into sending info back, but I've had no luck. In my JSON file I have an array which I would like to add-on to through the use of Xcode. I've tried many things to no avail.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{ @"myArray":@"NewObject"};
NSData* postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url going to JSON file"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url1];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

I based this code on another post, but I clearly don't understand, because its not adding anything to the JSON array. Just to clarify, I want to make it so that the new object that is added stays in the .json file.

EDIT: Since there is a bit of confusion Im posting the JSON code

```
{
"mykey": "myvalue",
"myarray": [
    "one",
    "two"
]
}
```

The objective is so that in the .json file in the "myarray" it would be "one","two","NewObject". The text "NewObject" would be a string that is coming from Xcode . Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line, NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{ @"myArray":@"NewObject"}; ?

Comment: Well I don't think its the right syntax, but I would like the string "NewObject" to enter the array that is located in the .json file

Comment: Your code doesn't show any array.  What are you trying to add to what?

Comment: I added the json code which contains the array, I edited the post so you can see the json

Comment: I still don't see any array in your code.  If you want something in place of `@"NewObject"` you're going to have to create it.

Comment: (BTW, in JSON character case is significant.)

Comment: Okay, there is no array in Xcode, but there is an array in the .json file (myarray). So what I'm attempting to do is take the string that is located in Xcode and place it in the array located in the .json file. Is that possible? to place a string inside an array thats located in a .json file or, I have to create an array in Xcode and completely replace the array located in the .json file?

Comment: Yeah it was the same caps, it was just my computers auto correct

Comment: You have a dictionary to represent the outermost "layer" of the JSON.  Put an array in that dictionary, then tell NSJSONSerialization to serialize the whole thing.  If you want to modify an array that's in a JSON string, convert the string to iOS objects with `JSONObjectWithData`, specifying the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option, then access the resulting iOS objects to modify the array as you need.  Then re-serialize.